# Unknown toolbar margin while using Design library android

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

How can I remove the start and end margin from the toolbar?

[image]

**Below is my xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.test.activities.topup.CreditCardDetailsVerification">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_credit_card_details_verification"/>
```

**style.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

**style.xml (v21)**

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: try this property 

        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"

Comment: check the AppTheme.AppBarOverlay. My best guess it that you might have accidently put it in the styles.xml Check all the styles.xml(v21, etc)

Comment: @DivyangPanchal - Not working

Comment: is this the parent layout for activity or it has some other parent?? and can you check the styles??

Comment: please post the theme `@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay`

Comment: @Budius - Added theme for appbaroverlay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was `<item name="android:backgroundTint">@android:color/transparent</item>` which causing this issue. I removed it and margin from start and end of toolbar is also removed.